# Please help me how this 3 if conditions works

Tags: php

This is my 3 if conditions, if these 3 conditions false then the image has to display.

```
$nameac=$_product->getName();
$array='product1,product2,product3,product4';
if (in_array($nameac,$array)){
    if ($_product->isSaleable()) {
        if ($apple=='Apple'||$currentCategoryId=='52') {
    } else {
        echo' <img src="image.jpg" width="50" height="50" class="onsaleicon" />';
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can negate a boolean result (using the `!` operator). So if you want to check for all conditions to be false, do the following:

```
if (
    !in_array($nameac,$array) && 
    !$_product->isSaleable() && 
    !($apple=='Apple'||$currentCategoryId=='52')
){
    echo' <img src="image.jpg" width="50" height="50" class="onsaleicon" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a string instead of an array in your code.

The way to create an array in php is as follows:

```
$array = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");
```

For more information: [PHP: Arrays - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thank u very much joren.... it worked for me...

Comment: Please mark this answer as the accepted answer if it solved your question by clicking the check mark under the vote counter.